# How to understand data storage for a React app?

Tags: reactjs, database, hosting

I am learning web dev and I am planning on developing a simple web app using React: a decision matrix tool.  I need users to be able log in and save their matrices under their profile so I prefer to not use LocalStorage and thus learn more about databases. I am thinking of using JSON as the data format and I will also need to store basics user data for login and their profile.  I wonder how to tackle such a project since so far I have only been using GitHub Pages to host my static websites. Most of what I find by googling seems confusing or irrelevant for such a small-sized project.
 My questions are:

1. What is the simplest way to store, access and edit JSON data as well as user data for a web app?
2. Are there any simple databases that can be “hosted” together with the app files on a server? Not sure if the question makes sense but I don’t understand where the database is.
3. What article or resource would you recommend to understand the concepts for data storage?

Comment: Have a look at `Supabase` , an open source alternative to `firebase` . Also , if you use NextJS , next-auth is fairly easy to setup authentication and you can create api to do backend tasks with it and connect a MongoDB instance (or any other db) with it.

Comment: If I use MongoDB locally when I develop my app, how will it work when I deploy my app on a server? Do I need to install MongoDB on the server first?

Comment: MongoDB is database , you either would have a local copy of it when developing or you can create a MongoDB instance from atlas for free (512MB) for development , they give a link and u download a ORM like mongoose to interact with it. So , its your choice if you want dont want to change the url you can . I haven't worked with MongoDB in prod . But personally , I think you should preferably choose Firebase or something along those lines

Comment: Ok it makes sense. Thanks @AnkushVerma

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would want to create a backend server using any language/framework e.g nodejs, java, django, php etc and expose the required data through [APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API). But, if you don't want to create a separate backend app you can use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/?gclid=CjwKCAjw-ZCKBhBkEiwAM4qfF0BsF2gXIAA9aHgKmcMuXTgtq-2m-xm4KTEj9HHYj94at6DIzx-o9RoCbY0QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) database [Firestore](https://www.google.com/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwjolKyi0oXzAhWKEJEKHdEgBIwYABAAGgJjZQ&ei=0VhEYdSHOuLf1sQPheON0AY&sig=AOD64_3sQfNoyhqqOggB8_GcGVD4NXWGSg&q&nis=1&sqi=2&adurl&ved=2ahUKEwiUtKai0oXzAhXir5UCHYVxA2oQ0Qx6BAgCEAE) to save and fetch all of your required data. You can even use firebase hosting to deploy your app. Moreover, firebase also have their [Authentication](https://www.google.com/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwjim8zO0oXzAhUSgVAGHZ-tC2UYABAAGgJkZw&sig=AOD64_1mEpBgcII4HKk0k3lGc7hGUKv4gA&q&nis=1&adurl&ved=2ahUKEwj1gsTO0oXzAhWGHhQKHU-aCigQ0Qx6BAgCEAE) service which you can leverage for your app's authentication.